# How to update field of object in array with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to find a **room** by **id** and update **received** field to **true** where **user id** equals to **xx**.

The document is here:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e5d0d870fc69641a41a3c65"),
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e57d64d92cc878760086980"), 
        ObjectId("5e57d64592cc87876008697e")
    ],
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e67834b6c8b2d356a4ad9fd"),
            "text" : "Hello",
            "user" : ObjectId("5e57d64d92cc878760086980"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-10T12:08:43.006Z"),
            "sent" : true,
            "received" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e6783076c8b2d356a4ad9fc"),
            "text" : "Hello",
            "user" : ObjectId("5e57d64d92cc878760086980"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-10T12:07:35.544Z"),
            "sent" : true,
            "received" : true
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-03-02T13:43:35.522Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-03-10T12:08:43.006Z"),
    "unReads" : {
        "5e57d64d92cc878760086980" : 1,
        "5e57d64592cc87876008697e" : 5
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

****It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.****

Comment: Can you show the document you're trying to update?

Comment: @mickl updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [the positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/):

```
Model.update({_id: ObjectId("5e5d0d870fc69641a41a3c65"), "messages.user": ObjectId("5e57d64d92cc878760086980")}, { $set: { "messages.$.received": true } })
```