# Mongoose: Find parent and update nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Problem**

I have the following object:

```
[
   {
      "_id":"1",
      "store":"llama.com",
      "items":[
         {
            "_id":"1_1",
            "name":"item1"
         },
         {
            "_id":"1_2",
            "name":"item2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "_id":"2",
      "store":"frog.com",
      "items":[
         {
            "_id":"2_1",
            "name":"item1"
         },
         {
            "_id":"2_2",
            "name":"item2"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

In this object, I need to:

1. Find the store;
2. Find an `item` by `_id`
3. Update the item's name

**Solutions tried**

I tried using `aggregate` but I'm only able to find the object, not modify it:

```
const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
const item = await UserModel.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$items" },
  {
    $match: { store, "items._id": ObjectId("1_1") },
  },
]);
```

**Desired outcome**

How can I find an item by `store`, then find the item child by `_id` and finally change the name of the found `item`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60617201/how-to-update-field-of-object-in-array-with-mongoose/60620752#60620752 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `store` and `items._id` you put your variables that you want to search.
`$set` changes the name here.

This works for 1 level nested array. For deeper nested arrays you should go with `arrayFilters` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#arrayfilters

```
const item = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    store: "some store",
    "items._id": "your id"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      [`items.$.` + variable]: "change your name"
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to make the `items.$.name` dynamic? For instance, if I had other keys that I wanted to update the value besides `name`, how could I achieve that?

Comment: sure, i have updated the answer. it looks ugly but should work @DiegoFortes

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

See if this works

```
   const item = await UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "store": "storeName", 
                "items._id" : "id" },{$set:{"items.0.name":"itemName"}}, {new: true})
```